# SilverStripe Fluent field icons

Tags: php, silverstripe

In the back-end, the SilverStripe Fluent module adds a green flag icon to indicate the field is translatable (as seen next to PageName, URL Segment and Content).

This is a userfriendly detail and I would expect it work for custom added CMS Fields which are made translatable. For example, I've added a custom field named `Introduction` and made it translatable using: `private static $translate = array( 'Introduction' );` But there is no green icon next to it. **Can this be added?**

[image: No green icon next to image]

Comment: Can you share your fluent yaml config?

Comment: Sure, this one `mysite/config/Fluent.yml` right? Here it is: https://gist.github.com/Faloude/118c7a798f7f96928f508bd96f1292e3

Comment: And this is one is `fluent/_config/fluent.yml`: https://gist.github.com/Faloude/df1d056036c0bdbe9557916fbc8acc35

Comment: You need to apply the FluentExtension to your DataObject in your mysite fluent.yml

Comment: This isn't a DataObject, it's an additional CMS Field in a Page type

Comment: Your Page type is a DataObject no? Most classes are up the tree.

Comment: Technically it is a DataObject indeed so I gave it a shot in 2 copies (SS 3.3 and SS 3.2). The green flag icon is still not there unfortunately.

Comment: Did you clear your cache manifest each time?

Comment: Yes, certainly. I'm starting to suspect that this actually just a lacking feature to the mod. I've posted this to github as well: https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/issues/195

Comment: Let's see what Damian says on GitHub. I guarantee it's a configuration problem

Comment: does your getCMSFields `$this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);`? See [link]https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/configuration.md[/link]

Comment: can you share the getCMSField() method where you add the "Introduction" field? I guess the problem is how you added it...

Comment: Indeed that's where the issue was: https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/dataobjects.md#default-field-scaffolder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was necessary to add `$this->beforeUpdateCMSFields(function($fields) { ... }` BEFORE `$fields = parent::getCMSFields();` and put all translatable fields in there like so:

```
function getCMSFields() {

    //This needs to be added for Fluent to apply css
    $this->beforeUpdateCMSFields(function($fields) {
        //Translatable field
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextAreaField('Introduction','Introduction'), 'Content');
    });

    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    //Non-translatable field
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", $uploadField = new UploadField('Slideshow', 'Slideshow Images'), 'Content');

    return $fields;
}
```